# TouchableOpacity onPress hangs inside ListView

Tags: javascript, listview, reactjs, react-native, react-native-listview

I have this ListView UI that started to run slowly once I added the `rowData` parameter inside the `onPress` event handler of TouchableOpacity. Once the TouchableOpacity is pressed, it stays pressed for 15 seconds and then again runs smoothly.

There seems to be some collision, because I use `rowData` also in the `renderRow` event handler of ListView three lines above.

Am I right and how to solve this problem?

```
<ListView
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true}
    renderRow={(rowData) =>
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={(rowData) => {
                console.log(rowData);//ON THIS LINE IT HANGS 15s
            }}
        >
            <Text>{rowData}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    }
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
/>
```

Comment: How large is the data inside of rowData ?

Comment: Around 5 objects, the slowness might be enhanced by running in debug mode.

Comment: it's the event (see below comment, also by ). The event is huge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd be really interested in the explanation of what makes this such an expensive operation in javascript, but the problem is that you're passing `rowData` as an argument to your `onPress` function, when `rowData` is already declared in the upper scope (`renderRow`).  So yes, just like you said, there's a collision.

Effectively, the value of `rowData` is being redefined by `onPress`, since the `onPress` function receives the touch event as an argument.  (You'll notice that the data being logged isn't actually your original row data, but a touch event object).

You can fix this by simply renaming the first argument of your `onPress` function.  e.g.

```
 <TouchableOpacity
       onPress={(evt) => {
         console.log(rowData); //now it doesn't hang
       }}
 >
```

Comment: Here is the explanation. The original rowData is the evt, as MichaelHelvey said. When you try to console.log the evt, it is huge.

You can verify this by putting in a console.log(Object.keys(evt)). That's fast.
Furthermore, if you want to actually look at the event, better to put in a debugger. The difference is the debugger will console.log the object and give you expanding-tree to see the deeper levels. console.log without the debugger isn't interactive. Hence, it tries to print out the whole tree. It is about the size of a DOM with lots of extra methods.

Answer (score 1):

Can we put header with Webview ? like

render() { // eslint-disable-line class-methods-use-this
    return (

```
  <Container theme={theme} style={{ backgroundColor: theme.defaultBackgroundColor }}>
    <Header style={{ justifyContent: 'flex-start', paddingTop: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 23 : 9 }}>
      <Button transparent onPress={() => this.popRoute()} >
       <Icon name="ios-arrow-round-back-outline" style={{ fontSize: 30, lineHeight: 32, paddingRight: 10 }} />
        Find Stores
      </Button>
   </Header>

  <WebView
      ref={WEBVIEW_REF}
      automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
      source={{uri: this.state.url}}
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
      domStorageEnabled={true}
      decelerationRate="normal"
      onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
      onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={this.onShouldStartLoadWithRequest}
      startInLoadingState={true}
      scalesPageToFit={this.state.scalesPageToFit}
    />

  </Container>
);
```